# Get id from first textarea inside form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which is stylized in the following way:

```
<form>
  <input>
  <textarea> <!-- I want this id -->
    <div>
     <textarea>
     <input>
    </div>
</form>
```

Between many attempts I've been left with my last attempt as `$(form).next('textarea').attr('id');` **It's not because I have $(form), that is working correctly.** The problem is with `.next('textarea').attr('id');` which is logging *undefined*. Any help on this one?

Comment: Use `.find` instead. The jQuery documentation provides enough information about DOM traversal methods: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/. The documentation about `next` says: *"Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector."*. That alone should already have told you that `.next` is not the correct method to use. The textarea is not a *sibling* of the form element.

Comment: Native JavaScript - `document.querySelector("form textarea").id;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is

```
$(form).find('textarea').first().attr('id');
```

As stated in the comments `.first()` isn't necessary since when you call `.attr()` it takes the attribute from the first element selected.

Comment: `.first` is not even necessary (but it can't hurt to be explicit).

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('form textarea').attr('id')`

see http://jsfiddle.net/fL8cy/